# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'sqlite3.Row'

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a python application in flask, this app uses SQLite as an sql server. this app needs to get the variable 'likes' from the database, but the file is being turned up as a sqlite3.Row not the integer i'm looking for.

```
@bp.route('/<int:id>/like', methods=('POST', 'GET'))
def like(id):
    db = get_db()
    db.commit()
    likes = get_db().execute(
        'SELECT likes FROM post WHERE id = 1'
    ).fetchone()
    
    print(int(likes))

    return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))
```

when python gets to `print(int(likes))` it turns up the error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'sqlite3.Row'`

I don't have much experience with the SQLite python module and, I don't know much about SQL. and am working on learning these, but nothing seems to help me.

Comment: You're getting a row, and even if there is one element in the row, it's still a row. You should use `.fetchone()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

turns out that to fix the problem I just needed to add `[0]` to the end of fetchone making it `.fetchone()[0]` thanks Michael.